# Why std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio isn't implemented in libc++ (clang)?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, clang, libc++

Let's look on this code example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int buf;
        std::cin >> buf;
    }
}
```

Performance of this code sample on input like this:

```
10000000
0
1
...
9999999
```

on my machine:

**g++-5 -O2 -std=c++11:**

```
./a.out < input.txt  0.86s user 0.07s system 98% cpu 0.942 total
```

**clang-700.0.72 -O2 -std=c++11**:

```
./a.out < input.txt  38.69s user 0.21s system 99% cpu 39.248 total
```

After some profiling I found that libc++ doesn't disable synchronization at all.

Then I look at their code and found this:
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/6a85e8a355be05b9efa8408f875014e6b47cef3b/src/ios.cpp#L458

So my question, is it by design or bug?

Comment: Is what ok? What's your question?

Comment: He might be asking if it's working properly or if it's a bug.

Comment: According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) *It is implementation-defined if this function has any effect if called after some I/O occurred on the standard stream.* Though it seems that does not apply here.

Comment: Just like "seeming to work" is a valid form of undefined behavior, "seeming to be synchronized" is a valid way for "unsynchronized" streams to behave. It's conforming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sync_with_stdio` is just an advisory function, as far as I can tell.

ios.members.static/2 says:

> *Effects:* If any input or output operation has occurred using the standard streams prior to the call, the effect is implementation-defined. Otherwise, called with a false argument, it allows the standard streams to operate independently of the standard C streams.

"allows ... to operate independently" is the key, IMHO.

There's no requirement on an implementation to actually do so, but rather, a prohibition on doing so *unless* this call has been made.

So, yes, this is conforming behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a correctness bug in terms of the behavior of iostream. There is a slight nuance though,

As per: https://eel.is/c++draft/ios.members.static

> Returns: true if the previous state of the standard iostream objects was synchronized and otherwise returns false.
> The first time it is called, the function returns true.

The return value of function `sync_with_stdio` value doesn't reflect the true behavior currently. It will return `false` after `sync_with_stdio(false)` has been called once. But `iostream` objects continue to sync with respective `cstdio` streams.

so the following program returns:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio();
    return 0;
}
```

```
true
false
```

For both libcxx and libstdc++.

Reference: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/ios#L327

---

The current implementation also has big impact on performance.

Due to this `getline` is significantly slower in libcxx as has been reported here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/21566